# SwiftUI List "Generic parameter 'S' could not be inferred"

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I am trying to show a SwiftUI List and get the error, "Generic parameter 'S' could not be inferred". I have tried changing it to a ForEach, but get the same error at the ForEach. The location of the error has a comment below.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

@available(iOS 13.3, *)
struct MyCustomerListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var custObservable: CustomersObservable = CustomersObservable()

    init()
    {
        UITableView.appearance().tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: Double.leastNonzeroMagnitude))
    }

    var body: some View {
        List(custObservable.customers) { cust in  //  <-- Error is here on List
            NavigationLink(destination: MultipleSignatureView(customer: cust)) {
                Text(cust.companyName)
            }
        }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }
}

@available(iOS 13.3, *)
class CustomersObservable: ObservableObject {
    @Published var customers: [Cust] = [Cust]()

    init() {
        customers.append(contentsOf: [
            Cust(id: "u", companyName: "Uinta"),
            Cust(id: "v", companyName: "victor"),
            Cust(id: "w", companyName: "wasden")
        ])
    }
}

@available(iOS 13.3, *)
class Cust: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var companyName: String

    init(id: String, companyName: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.companyName = companyName
    }
}
```

What could it be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what version are using? i can compile with 13.3

Comment: xcode version is 11.3.1 (11C504). Swift verison 5. Since it won't compile, I am not trying to run it on a device yet.

Comment: No error with Xcode 11.4

Comment: Ok, thanks Chris, @Asperi, in a new project it is compiling for me as well, both on xcode 11.3.1 and 11.4. So it is something with my project. I thought maybe it was a namespace issue, so I put SwiftUI.List(custObservable..., to qualify it, and still the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The error was not intuitive at all. My problem was in this code:

```
NavigationLink(destination: MultipleSignatureView(customer: cust)) { // <-- wrong type passed
    Text(cust.companyName)
}
```

My MultipleSignatureView class took a String instead of the Cust object. Once I made the change to my MultipleSignatureView constructor, allowing it to receive a Cust object, it worked.

Thanks to those that commented. It is obvious in hindsight that since the code I posted compiled on other systems, that my question should have included my related object. In case someone has a similar problem I will provide my before and after code here:

Before:

```
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 13.3, *)
struct MultipleSignatureView: View {
    var customer: String     // <-- It was choking here. Cust object was being passed
    var body: some View {
        Text(customer)
    }
}
```

After:

```
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 13.3, *)
struct MultipleSignatureView: View {
    var customer: Cust               // <-- Now it takes a Cust object
    var body: some View {
        Text(customer.companyName)
    }
}
```